# setting environment vars in uboot escape sequences

Tags: environment-variables, u-boot

I have an existing environment which looks like:

```
printenv
preboot=echo;echo Type \"run flash_nfs\" to mount root filesystem over NFS;echo
```

How can I set exactly this value?

I tried:

```
setenv preboot 'echo\;echo Type \"run flash_nfs\" to mount root filesystem over NFS\;echo'
printenv
preboot=echo;echo Type "run flash_nfs" to mount root filesystem over NFS;echo
```

and

```
setenv preboot 'echo\;echo Type \\"run flash_nfs\\" to mount root filesystem over NFS\;echo'
printenv
preboot=echo;echo Type \\"run flash_nfs\\" to mount root filesystem over NFS;echo
```

How can I set the sequence `\"` as part of a var?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details?  Currently, and for **sandbox** you can do:

```
=> setenv test 'echo;echo \\"foo\\"'
=> run test                         

"foo"
=> printenv test
test=echo;echo \"foo\"
=>
```